# Google Table Chart from php created Json

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I am trying to create a Google Table Chart with information I have exported from my database with php and encoded to json. (momJson.php)  I am getting a blank page and I am not sure why.  Any help would be very much appreciated!!

PS I can make a table straight from the mysql database with php, but I want to use the same information to make multiple charts, so I thought I would start with an easy one.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: "momJson.php",
     dataType:"json",
     async: false
     }).responseText;  

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

 var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSON Data (I did validate at JSONLint.com)

```
[{"schoolid":"10007","prizeprogram":"APP","datereceived":"20160415","numberstudents":"292","participatingstudents":"69","studentresponse":"0.23","numberbooklets":"91","numbernames":"762","numberorders":"43","orderresponse":"0.05","tov":"1606.52","numbersubscriptions":"64","saleweek":"160122","vpn":"2.10","vps":"5.50","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Iaeger Elementary School","schoolcity":"Iaeger","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"A","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10013","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160208","numberstudents":"256","participatingstudents":"58","studentresponse":"0.22","numberbooklets":"78","numbernames":"638","numberorders":"54","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"2111.23","numbersubscriptions":"80","saleweek":"160108","vpn":"3.30","vps":"8.24","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Mount Hope Elementary School","schoolcity":"Mount Hope","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10027","prizeprogram":"RBR","datereceived":"20150914","numberstudents":"315","participatingstudents":"49","studentresponse":"0.15","numberbooklets":"57","numbernames":"540","numberorders":"52","orderresponse":"0.09","tov":"1716.61","numbersubscriptions":"73","saleweek":"150904","vpn":"3.17","vps":"5.44","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"8","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Webster Springs Elementary School","schoolcity":"Webster Springs","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10051","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150923","numberstudents":"240","participatingstudents":"41","studentresponse":"0.17","numberbooklets":"53","numbernames":"459","numberorders":"56","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"1745.10","numbersubscriptions":"69","saleweek":"150911","vpn":"3.80","vps":"7.27","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"4","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Sutton Elementary School","schoolcity":"Sutton","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10052","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160217","numberstudents":"675","participatingstudents":"212","studentresponse":"0.31","numberbooklets":"241","numbernames":"2338","numberorders":"287","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"10415.68","numbersubscriptions":"407","saleweek":"160129","vpn":"4.45","vps":"15.43","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Daniels Elementary School","schoolcity":"Daniels","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"5","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10053","prizeprogram":"RSWB","datereceived":"20160205","numberstudents":"351","participatingstudents":"204","studentresponse":"0.58","numberbooklets":"231","numbernames":"2250","numberorders":"391","orderresponse":"0.17","tov":"14056.06","numbersubscriptions":"545","saleweek":"160115","vpn":"6.24","vps":"40.04","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Arthur I Boreman Elementary School","schoolcity":"Middlebourne","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10057","prizeprogram":"RSWS","datereceived":"20160302","numberstudents":"265","participatingstudents":"64","studentresponse":"0.24","numberbooklets":"84","numbernames":"707","numberorders":"106","orderresponse":"0.14","tov":"3932.80","numbersubscriptions":"158","saleweek":"160205","vpn":"5.56","vps":"14.84","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Eastbrook Elementary School","schoolcity":"Winfield","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10065","prizeprogram":"RBR","datereceived":"20150921","numberstudents":"210","participatingstudents":"26","studentresponse":"0.12","numberbooklets":"34","numbernames":"290","numberorders":"42","orderresponse":"0.14","tov":"1539.27","numbersubscriptions":"60","saleweek":"150911","vpn":"5.30","vps":"7.32","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Salt Rock Elementary School","schoolcity":"Salt Rock","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10066","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150828","numberstudents":"220","participatingstudents":"67","studentresponse":"0.30","numberbooklets":"94","numbernames":"743","numberorders":"66","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"2371.85","numbersubscriptions":"96","saleweek":"150814","vpn":"3.19","vps":"10.78","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Cox Landing Elementary School","schoolcity":"Lesage","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10095","prizeprogram":"APP","datereceived":"20160223","numberstudents":"300","participatingstudents":"50","studentresponse":"0.16","numberbooklets":"63","numbernames":"552","numberorders":"49","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"1857.94","numbersubscriptions":"77","saleweek":"160122","vpn":"3.36","vps":"6.19","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"6","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Beale Elementary School","schoolcity":"Gallipolis Ferry","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"A","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10104","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150929","numberstudents":"80","participatingstudents":"35","studentresponse":"0.43","numberbooklets":"45","numbernames":"386","numberorders":"48","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"1708.43","numbersubscriptions":"67","saleweek":"150918","vpn":"4.42","vps":"21.35","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Hillsboro Elementary School","schoolcity":"Hillsboro","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10143","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150915","numberstudents":"400","participatingstudents":"172","studentresponse":"0.43","numberbooklets":"206","numbernames":"1899","numberorders":"193","orderresponse":"0.10","tov":"6286.01","numbersubscriptions":"251","saleweek":"150821","vpn":"3.31","vps":"15.71","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"2","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Moorefield Elementary School","schoolcity":"Moorefield","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10159","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160203","numberstudents":"165","participatingstudents":"68","studentresponse":"0.41","numberbooklets":"89","numbernames":"756","numberorders":"48","orderresponse":"0.06","tov":"1588.47","numbersubscriptions":"65","saleweek":"160108","vpn":"2.10","vps":"9.62","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Prichard Elementary School","schoolcity":"Prichard","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"}]
```

Comment: check for error's in the console? please share a sample of `jsonData`

Comment: I added the jsondata returned by the momJson.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to create a [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) directly from the `jsonData`,
it must be in a format google understands

following is an example of the standard format,
found in the examples under the reference for the [`DataTable` constructor method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1)

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  cols: [
    {id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
    {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}
  ],
  rows: [
    {c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}
  ]
});
```

if the `jsonData` is not in this format, then it must be manipulated accordingly

there are several ways to add columns and rows to a `DataTable`

in the following working snippet,
the keys from the first object `{}` in the `jsonData` are used to create the columns

also, recommend **not** using `async: false`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    // get json
    $.ajax({
      url: "momJson.php",
      dataType:"json"
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      // success
      drawTable(jsonData);
    }).fail(function (jq, text) {
      // failure
      //console.log(text);

      // included here for example purposes
      drawTable([{"schoolid":"10007","prizeprogram":"APP","datereceived":"20160415","numberstudents":"292","participatingstudents":"69","studentresponse":"0.23","numberbooklets":"91","numbernames":"762","numberorders":"43","orderresponse":"0.05","tov":"1606.52","numbersubscriptions":"64","saleweek":"160122","vpn":"2.10","vps":"5.50","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Iaeger Elementary School","schoolcity":"Iaeger","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"A","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10013","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160208","numberstudents":"256","participatingstudents":"58","studentresponse":"0.22","numberbooklets":"78","numbernames":"638","numberorders":"54","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"2111.23","numbersubscriptions":"80","saleweek":"160108","vpn":"3.30","vps":"8.24","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Mount Hope Elementary School","schoolcity":"Mount Hope","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10027","prizeprogram":"RBR","datereceived":"20150914","numberstudents":"315","participatingstudents":"49","studentresponse":"0.15","numberbooklets":"57","numbernames":"540","numberorders":"52","orderresponse":"0.09","tov":"1716.61","numbersubscriptions":"73","saleweek":"150904","vpn":"3.17","vps":"5.44","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"8","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Webster Springs Elementary School","schoolcity":"Webster Springs","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10051","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150923","numberstudents":"240","participatingstudents":"41","studentresponse":"0.17","numberbooklets":"53","numbernames":"459","numberorders":"56","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"1745.10","numbersubscriptions":"69","saleweek":"150911","vpn":"3.80","vps":"7.27","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"4","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Sutton Elementary School","schoolcity":"Sutton","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10052","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160217","numberstudents":"675","participatingstudents":"212","studentresponse":"0.31","numberbooklets":"241","numbernames":"2338","numberorders":"287","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"10415.68","numbersubscriptions":"407","saleweek":"160129","vpn":"4.45","vps":"15.43","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Daniels Elementary School","schoolcity":"Daniels","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"5","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10053","prizeprogram":"RSWB","datereceived":"20160205","numberstudents":"351","participatingstudents":"204","studentresponse":"0.58","numberbooklets":"231","numbernames":"2250","numberorders":"391","orderresponse":"0.17","tov":"14056.06","numbersubscriptions":"545","saleweek":"160115","vpn":"6.24","vps":"40.04","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Arthur I Boreman Elementary School","schoolcity":"Middlebourne","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10057","prizeprogram":"RSWS","datereceived":"20160302","numberstudents":"265","participatingstudents":"64","studentresponse":"0.24","numberbooklets":"84","numbernames":"707","numberorders":"106","orderresponse":"0.14","tov":"3932.80","numbersubscriptions":"158","saleweek":"160205","vpn":"5.56","vps":"14.84","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Eastbrook Elementary School","schoolcity":"Winfield","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10065","prizeprogram":"RBR","datereceived":"20150921","numberstudents":"210","participatingstudents":"26","studentresponse":"0.12","numberbooklets":"34","numbernames":"290","numberorders":"42","orderresponse":"0.14","tov":"1539.27","numbersubscriptions":"60","saleweek":"150911","vpn":"5.30","vps":"7.32","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Salt Rock Elementary School","schoolcity":"Salt Rock","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10066","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150828","numberstudents":"220","participatingstudents":"67","studentresponse":"0.30","numberbooklets":"94","numbernames":"743","numberorders":"66","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"2371.85","numbersubscriptions":"96","saleweek":"150814","vpn":"3.19","vps":"10.78","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Cox Landing Elementary School","schoolcity":"Lesage","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10095","prizeprogram":"APP","datereceived":"20160223","numberstudents":"300","participatingstudents":"50","studentresponse":"0.16","numberbooklets":"63","numbernames":"552","numberorders":"49","orderresponse":"0.08","tov":"1857.94","numbersubscriptions":"77","saleweek":"160122","vpn":"3.36","vps":"6.19","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"6","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Beale Elementary School","schoolcity":"Gallipolis Ferry","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:32","testcode":"A","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10104","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150929","numberstudents":"80","participatingstudents":"35","studentresponse":"0.43","numberbooklets":"45","numbernames":"386","numberorders":"48","orderresponse":"0.12","tov":"1708.43","numbersubscriptions":"67","saleweek":"150918","vpn":"4.42","vps":"21.35","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Hillsboro Elementary School","schoolcity":"Hillsboro","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10143","prizeprogram":"WCR","datereceived":"20150915","numberstudents":"400","participatingstudents":"172","studentresponse":"0.43","numberbooklets":"206","numbernames":"1899","numberorders":"193","orderresponse":"0.10","tov":"6286.01","numbersubscriptions":"251","saleweek":"150821","vpn":"3.31","vps":"15.71","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"PK","highgrade":"2","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Moorefield Elementary School","schoolcity":"Moorefield","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:34","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"},{"schoolid":"10159","prizeprogram":"RSR","datereceived":"20160203","numberstudents":"165","participatingstudents":"68","studentresponse":"0.41","numberbooklets":"89","numbernames":"756","numberorders":"48","orderresponse":"0.06","tov":"1588.47","numbersubscriptions":"65","saleweek":"160108","vpn":"2.10","vps":"9.62","schoolcat":"7","lowgrade":"K","highgrade":"5","schooltype":"E","schoolname":"Prichard Elementary School","schoolcity":"Prichard","schoolstate":"WV","dateupdated":"2016-06-06 11:57:33","testcode":"","mdrcode":"1\r"}]);
    });

  },
  packages:['table']
});

function drawTable(jsonData) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  jsonData.forEach(function (row, index) {
    // load columns
    if (index === 0) {
      Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
        data.addColumn({
          label: key,
          type: 'string'
        });
      });
    }

    // load rows
    var dataRow = [];
    // load value for each column
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      // ensure each row has value for key
      if (row.hasOwnProperty(data.getColumnLabel(i))) {
        dataRow.push(row[data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
      } else {
        dataRow.push(null);
      }
    }
    data.addRow(dataRow);
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

for custom column labels, load each manually, rather than using results from data...

```
function drawTable(jsonData) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  // load columns

  // School Id
  data.addColumn({
    label: 'School Id',
    type: 'string'
  });

  // Prize Program
  data.addColumn({
    label: 'Prize Program',
    type: 'string'
  });

  // Date Received
  data.addColumn({
    label: 'Date Received',
    type: 'string'
  });

  // # of Students
  data.addColumn({
    label: '# of Students',
    type: 'string'
  });

  // # of Participating Students
  data.addColumn({
    label: '# of Participating Students',
    type: 'string'
  });

  jsonData.forEach(function (row, index) {
    // load rows
    var dataRow = [];
    // load value for each column
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      // ensure each row has value for key
      if (row.hasOwnProperty(data.getColumnLabel(i))) {
        dataRow.push(row[data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
      } else {
        dataRow.push(null);
      }
    }
    data.addRow(dataRow);
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
}
```

Comment: So the "Included here for example purposes" I need to put the results of my json encode there?  Sorry I'm such a novice, but I'm not sure I understand exactly how to convert mysqli query to json data that google can read. i thought I was doing that, and your answer is working perfectly, I just can't figure out how to add all of my database info to the drawTable function without entering it manually.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to confuse you, you should be able remove the example from the `.fail` callback -- I put it there because the ajax call will fail when running from here on SO -- but if you're json is formatted as it is in the question, and the ajax call doesn't fail, then the call to `drawTable` in the `.done` callback should produce the same result

Comment: I have one more question, if it's not too much trouble.  I really appreciate the help you provided with this!  Is it possible to change the labels for the column headings in the code above?  It works perfectly now, but the headings need to be more User Friendly than the database hast them

Comment: sure, see __EDIT__ to above answer, notice comment for `// load columns` in __EDIT__ and previous answer -- the previous answer loads the columns from the results, the __EDIT__ adds them manually, above the loop -- `jsonData.forEach` -- hope this helps...

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!